# Calling an MVC Action with JQuery AJAX that doesn't return Json (instead another view)

Tags: .net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, redirect

So I have an MVC Action in my controller

```
public System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Link(LinkType type)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case LinkType.IC:
                    return RedirectToAction("Indication", "IndicationsController");
                    break;
                case LinkType.Pricing:
                    break;
                case LinkType.Sheets:
                    break;
                case LinkType.Analysis:
                    break;
                case LinkType.Admin:
                    break;
                default : 
                    break;
            }

            return View(@"~\Views\Indications\ShowAString.aspx", "", "Page is not available for selection.");
        }
```

I want to call this action from JQuery passing the integer value of the button that was clicked. So I have this in my button click method:

```
$('#btnIc').live('click', function () {
        var typeJSON = {};
        typeJSON["type"] = 1;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<%= Url.Action("Link", "Home") %> ",
            dataType: "jsonData",
            data: typeJSON,
            success: function(data) {

            }
        });
    });
```

Will this redirect the page or will it be waiting for me to do something with (data)?

Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: Why are you not returning a `JsonResult` instead of a view?

Comment: not an asp expert, not at all, but ... i don't see anything there that hints to the fact that the output Should be json encoded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returning an entire view in an AJAX request is almost always not the way to go. Instead you want to return XML, JSON or a chunk of HTML. You can return a chunk of HTML by returning a partial by calling `PartialView()` in the Controller.

If you are returning HTML, then your jQuery AJAX request needs to be expecting it, so change its dataType to `html`. Then in the jQuery callback you can just take the received HTML and append it to your page somewhere.

NOTE: you can use `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` to return either AJAX data or a full view, and use the same action for both kinds of requests. This helps with progressive enhancement.

Comment: I want to call an action that returns another view. Basically, this is a Home Page and I want to choose, depending on the button, what other page to re-direct to.

Comment: But you can't do redirects like that with AJAX. Your AJAX request will get redirected, and it will ultimately receive something from the server, but the client's browser will remain put. If you want to redirect, you probably don't want AJAX at all.

Comment: Hmm okay. so I would I do a normal redirect?

Comment: It's hard to say, I'd need to see your code and your intentions. But generally speaking AJAX is for updating pieces of the current page. If you want to take the user to an entirely new page, you probably want to just do a normal HTTP request.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do

```
public ActionResult Link(LinkType type)
{
  var obj = ...; //Object that you get from the LinkType. Whatever ShowAString returns.
  return Json(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning json it looks like you are redirecting to another action that may be returning a view. You will need to set the type of the action to JsonResult and return your json object there.